# Sourcing Environments on Startup

Tags: command-line, bash, startup, bashrc, autostart

I am new Ubuntu user working Robot Operating System on 16.04 LTS version. I installed ROS using [their official ROS-Wiki instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation).

Every time I need to run an ROS program I need to source the ROS environment using:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

Every time I open new terminal I need to source the environment. Is it possible to write a shell script to do the sourcing job on start-up?

How can I make it common for all terminals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` sourced when you open a new interactive bash shell, put the `source` command at the end of the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

1. You may want to back it up (though if you haven't modified it then it's the same as `/etc/skel/.bashrc`). You can do by running:

   ```
   cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.orig
   ```
2. Open `~/.bashrc` in a text editor. To use the in-terminal editor `nano`:

   ```
   nano ~/.bashrc
   ```

   To use the GUI editor Gedit, replace `nano` with `gedit`.

   Add this line at the end of the file:

   ```
   source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
   ```
3. Save the file and quit the text editor.

Subsequently started interactive shells will bet set up for ROS.

You don't have to manually source `setup.bash` anymore. The change persists across logins and reboots, because `~/.bashrc` is itself automatically sourced, but *not* automatically modified, in interactive bash shells. But it applies only to your user account and only in bash.

If you want to undo it, just open `~/.bashrc` in a text editor and remove the line you added or comment it out by writing a `#` at the beginning of it. (Or restore the backup of the file.)

Comment: How can I make to auto launch the ```~/.bashrc``` on terminal startup?